# UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c

I try to scale my image and i want use Aspect Fit. But it doesn't work

```
solutionImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_solution@2x.png"]];
    // optional:
    solutionImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit; // content mode
    solutionImageView.center = CGPointMake((currentWidth)/2, currentHeight - (currentHeight/3.5));
    [self.view addSubview:solutionImageView];
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot with and without the contentMode?

Comment: What doesn't work?  Is the image bigger than you expect?  Set `clipsToBounds=true`

Comment: You are using @2x image and initWithImage. So the image view is created as per the size of 2x. So your contentMode will not work like you expected. Try to set the needed frame than setting center. Then contentMode will work.

Comment: [link] (https://monosnap.com/file/8dDbrh0vAWy5ra5X6M3qXTphLz8CTz.png)    nothing change if i use content mode or not, in both case i have same result

Comment: @Paulw11 solutionImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;  doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

As arunit21 said in his comment, when you create an UIImageView with the `initWithImage` method, the size of frame of the view is calculated with image size. So your image view is centered but bigger than you window.
You can do

```
solutionImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:yourFrame];
solutionImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_solution"];
solutionImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit; // content mode
solutionImageView.center = CGPointMake((currentWidth)/2, currentHeight - (currentHeight/3.5));
[self.view addSubview:solutionImageView];
```

You can also just set your new frame after your initialization to set the correct size.

The `@2x.png`is not needed in `[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_solution"]`. With this method, the system will check if the screen is retina and look for the `@2x`image if it exists and take the normal one otherwise.